# 'double dot' is not a valid command on git bash

Tags: javascript, npm, git-bash

I'm using window git bash, here's what I did:

1. git clone a project
2. run npm run dev

I got
`'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

the package.json look like this

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "../../node_modules/.bin/cypress open",
    "dev": "../../node_modules/.bin/start-test 7079 cypress:open",
  }
}
```

is this windows related issue?

I was trying to run https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes in windows.

Comment: If you’re running on windows why is the question tagged Linux?

Comment: @evolutionxbox because I was using mac I never got this issue, I'm new to window, I'm guessing it's window related issue

Comment: I am inclined to think that it is a git bash issue, not a general bash issue, and inasmuch as git bash is a build of bash specifically for Windows, yes, that makes it a Windows-related issue.

Comment: For example, the `/` character is typically used to introduce command-line options in Windows' traditional command interpreters, whereas it is the file separator character on Unix.  Possibly git bash implements Windows-like instead of Unix-like command-line interpretation.  If so, then it is probably unsuited for use with general bash scripts, which will make different assumptions.

Comment: Wrap the pathnames in your npm scripts with JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. \"...\". For example: `"dev": "\"../../node_modules/.bin/start-test\" 7079 cypress:open",` and `"cypress:open": "\"../../node_modules/.bin/cypress\" open",`

Comment: @RobC nope, no luck with that.

Comment: @RobC are you using window too? can you try to run this repo without error? https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes thanks

Comment: I doubt I need to make weird escape in the package.json file, I think that's not the issue.

Comment: *bash* never says "not recognized as an internal or external command"; that error message comes from `cmd.exe`. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41454769/1256452). Why cmd.exe is getting involved, I have no idea. This has nothing to do with Linux or Git, though (`git-bash` has nothing to do with Git either, despite the name), so I'm going to snip off a few tags.